# Does the Garbage collector collects static classes?

Tags: c#, .net, static, garbage-collection, static-classes

If I have something like :

```
   public static class StaticClass
    {
        public static int x;

        public static void Do(int y)
        {
            x = y;
        }

    }
```

You can't instantiate `StaticClass` , so when will the garbage collector take care of it ?

Will it remain in memory for the entire lifetime of the performing executing application ?

Comment: It will remain in memory until the application closes.

Comment: If your application is Asp.net then the static variable will be re-instantiated at the time of app pool recycle. Else, it will remain in memory until application restart/ close.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it remain in memory for the entire lifetime of the performing executing application ?

Yes.  Since there's effectively always a "reference" to the static object, it will never get garbage collected.